# Combining Pipe in Tr in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I have a very simple problem. It's about the writing the pipe inside the tr in reactive forms. I have this code

`<tr *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls; "let i = index" [formGroupName]="i"| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p }">`

. And i'm confused on why this is incorrect. Any syntax error in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It contains the extra double quotes and code sequence error, even if you want to write above code

you should write it like :

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p } ; let i = index"  [formGroupName]="i">
```

Comment: @Joseph, I have also solved the other issue , please check it out.